# how to make random backgorundcolor html5

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

First of all I want to give thanks for this social group known stackoverflow. I have been searching and I dont find nothing similar to resolve my problem.
I want to change the backgraoundcolor(degrade) in the header and footer each time that I recharge the page.
I have three files:

**index. html** inside header and footer a div known = backgraound

**styles.css** where I call the backgradound

**backgraound.js** where i try to do the logic to work all of this.

I dont know as to do to work this
I have try to do the next

```js
function ran_col() { //function name
  var color = document.getElementById('background').style.background = random;
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * color)];
  var arraybackground = ["backgroundmorado", "backgroundazul", "backgroundazuloscuro"];
  for (var i = 0; i <= arraybackground.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(arraybackground[i]).style.background = color;
  }
}
```

```css
    #backgroundmorado {
      background: #258dc8;
      /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #258dc8 0%, #8e2def 100%);
      /* FF3.6-15 */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #258dc8 0%, #8e2def 100%);
      /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(135deg, #258dc8 0%, #8e2def 100%);
      /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#258dc8', endColorstr='#8e2def', GradientType=1);
      /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
      height: 400px;
    }
    #backgroundazuloscuro {
      background: #1e5799;
      /* Old browsers */
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #1e5799 0%, #207cca 34%, #207cca 34%, #2989d8 50%, #d97be5 100%);
      /* FF3.6-15 */
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #1e5799 0%, #207cca 34%, #207cca 34%, #2989d8 50%, #d97be5 100%);
      /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1e5799 0%, #207cca 34%, #207cca 34%, #2989d8 50%, #d97be5 100%);
      /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#d97be5', GradientType=1);
      /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
      height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="background">
      <div class="container " align="center">
        <h1>My web</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <footer>
    <div class="container" align="center">
      <h4>Lorem ipsun</h4> 
    </div>
  </footer>
  <script src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
```

Can I help me somebody? thanks

Comment: What is happening instead? How is it going wrong? Also, side note, when the code is this long, it might be a good idea to put the full code in pastebin or something similar instead of putting it directly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're almost there, I just think your javascript needs a couple tweaks.

Check out this simplified example I knocked up:

http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/rLNLPx

```
function randomiseColor(){
   var colors = ['background-red','background-blue','background-green'];
   var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
   var d = document.getElementById("background");
   d.className += randomColor;
}
randomiseColor();
```

Similar to yourself, it generates a random index into an array of classes that dictate the div background color. The script runs on load, so it'll change the color each time the page opens.

Comment: thanks of all you for the answers. This code really it worked. The next problem is that the header work but the footer doesnt work. I think because I use the tag id. I try to change the  tag id  in the footer and header by class and the var d = document.getElementById("background"); by  var d = document.getElementsByClassName("background"))  line in file.js and still doesnt work. What happend? thanks

Comment: Impossible, I try and only can see the changes in the header, in the footer nothing. I think that i should do some for in js but i dont know where

Answer (score 0):

So there were a few issues:

- Set the css as a class name and not an ID
- Add the class name instead of changing the background color directly
- The first line of the original code was using `random` which wasn't even defined.
- Spurious `]` at the end of the second line.
- Use `Math.round` instead of `Math.floor` because the last entry in the array won't ever get used.

Try this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/uL6keuLv/1/)):

```
function ran_col() { //function name
  var arraybackground = ["backgroundmorado", "backgroundazul", "backgroundazuloscuro"];
  var len = arraybackground.length - 1;
  var random = Math.round(Math.random() * len);
  document.getElementById('background').className = arraybackground[random];
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  ran_col();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
function changeBack(){
    red = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
    green = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
    blue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 255));
    document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor="rgb(" + red + "," + green + "," + blue + ")";
    //alert(document.getElementById("background").style.backgroundColor);
    }

    changeBack();
```

Fairly simple...

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

elements = document.getElementsByClassName('bg');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor='#'+randomColor;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  Header Content  
</div>
<h3>Body</h3>
<div class="bg">
  Footer Content  
</div>
```